# Optimizing space for many shapes within an irregular shape

Tags: optimization, area

So let's say in a state, there are 50 schools dispersed throughout, given by Latitude Longitude points. How would we create distinct zones that optimize the space around each school? The goal is to give each zone as much padding as possible between the central points of other zones. Trying to clarify: each district wouldn't necessarily have to be the same size as long as the entire space is filled. Please ask questions and I will clarify! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to create a [Voronoi diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram) of the school sites.